# Missing native-platform.dll error

Tags: android, windows, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic application for my android project. when I try to build the app with the command "ionic build android", I'm getting the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for windows 8.1 amd64.
```

What would be the problem? and suggest me some solutions.

Comment: Did you check if you have all the necessary tools from the SDK?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the SDK till the latest release.